# How to delete duplicate records based on two unique columns in RedShift

Tags: sql, duplicates, amazon-redshift

I have the following table redshift.

| guest_id | name | rownum |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Safvan | 1 |
| 1 | Safvan | 2 |
| 1 | Thomas | 3 |
| 2 | Anandu | 1 |
| 2 | Manish | 2 |

I need to delete all the records in each partition based on guest_id except the record having max(rownum).

The result should be like

| guest_id | name | rownum |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Thomas | 3 |
| 2 | Manish | 2 |

Thanks in advance for valuable helps.

Comment: Please, show your current attempt and describe what is wrong with it.

Comment: that helped me somewhere..it is a good thread. I have posted my solution as answer.

Answer (score 1):

My solution is :

```
create table table_rownum as (
select
    *,
    row_number() over (partition by guest_id
order by
    rownum desc) as rownum_temp
from
    table_orig);

delete from table_rownum where rownum_temp<>1;

alter table table_rownum drop column rownum_temp;

truncate table table_orig;

insert into table_orig (select * from table_rownum);

drop table table_rownum;
```

Please suggest if there is better solution.

Comment: using CTE for removing duplicate records. Please check my answer. No need to create extra table and also perform drop or truncate. Only DELETE use for removing.

Answer (score 0):

Subquery returns guest_id wise max row then JOIN with main table where matching guest_id and max_row not equal row_num then perform DELETE.

```
DELETE redshift
FROM redshift r
INNER JOIN (SELECT guest_id
                 , MAX(rownum) rownum
           FROM redshift
           GROUP BY guest_id) t
        ON r.guest_id = t.guest_id
       AND r.rownum != t.rownum
```

Please check from https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=47081e3517000949460932808ac9f09d

Delete duplicate records by using CTE

```
WITH t_cte AS (
       SELECT *
            , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY guest_id ORDER BY rownum DESC) row_num
       FROM redshift
)
DELETE redshift 
FROM t_cte c
INNER JOIN redshift r
        ON c.guest_id = r.guest_id
       AND  c.row_num > 1 AND c.rownum = r.rownum
```

Please check from url https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=90b7099ca779c0836b90278ae1b3635a

Comment: Here when using with cte, the delete will hit the original table redshift? or you missed to put original table in the main query?

Comment: `WITH cte AS (
       SELECT *
            , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY guest_id ORDER BY rownum DESC) row_num
       FROM redshift
)
DELETE
FROM redshift rs
inner join cte on rs.rownum=cte.row_num
WHERE cte.row_num<>1;`


This is the correct query?

Comment: please check from given url where u can check data.

Comment: Redshift is basically built on Postgres, the query throwing error in Postgres.

Comment: you can use first query.

Comment: @safvan if my query helps you then mark it as accepted along with upvote so anyone can pick this without any doubt.

Comment: That is not a redshift query and it does not work for redshift!

Answer (score -3):

Delete from table name where rownum not in (select max(rownum) from table name groupby column)

Comment: It will delete all the data in the table if subquery returns more than one row.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).